# DataContext not visible when choosing data source for LinqDataSource

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, linq, datacontext

I have a page on which I've thrown a LinqDataSource and a GridView. I've created a DataContext LINQ-to-SQL class called dcResidents.dbml. When I attempt to configure the LinqDataSource to utilize the dcResidents data context - it doesn't appear in the list of options...though under class view (tab in VS) it does appear.
I do have several other working datacontexts - why is this one not being recognized by VS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is my work-around:

1. Remove data connections and re-add for SQL servers.
2. Reference DataContext in code-behind first, then try using drag-and-drop interface.

Answer (score 1):

Try to **Build** your project first ( Debug-menu > Bulid *Projectname* ) before you configure the DataSource-controls source.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; however, I solved it by verifying if the `System.Data.Linq` is referenced in `web.config` or not.

Strangely, it exsited under References of the project and compiler could compile the application successfully. However, when I wanted to view the application in browser, I received runtime error, which stated it cannot find the related assembly. So, I added that manually to the web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.30319.17929, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

I hope it solves your issue.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new local installation of my website and then opened in VS 2010, and this time it saw the Data Context. it means u first must be debug your project then saw the Data Context.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help for other peoples and save its time. In VS2017: 
 1. configure .dbml file, 
 2. save project changes, close and re-open IDE with your project. 
 3. try to continue configuration using your datacontext